# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autoreload' on 12.2 LTS

Tags: databricks, databricks-dbx

I am using [dbx](https://github.com/databrickslabs/dbx) to work on mixed-mode development loop. This is the [link](https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/python/devloop/mixed/?h=mix) in case you want to read about it.

This are the steps:

First cell:

```py
import autoreload
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Second cell:

```py
from pathlib import Path 
import sys

project_root = Path(".").absolute().parent
print(f"appending the main project code from {project_root}")
sys.path.append(project_root)
```

I was running the code perfectly with:

`11.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.0, Scala 2.12)`

I updated the cluster to:

`12.2 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.2, Scala 2.12)`

When doing so I got error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autoreload'`

I know about the issue with the extra space but it is not the case here.

**Does anyone know who to solve it?**

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this line:

```
import autoreload
```

this extension works without it even before 12.x versions

Comment: Thanks. I found that I do not. I needed on 11.3 LTS

Comment: just run without `import autoreload` on both 10.4 & 11.3, and everything works just fine